# How to sort image names with digits like 1,2,3,4..., not 10,11,12,13 in "drawable" folder?

Tags: android, android-studio

There are some images in my "drawable" folder and I want to know how to sort like `cat__1_, cat__2_...`, but don't start from `cat__10_, cat__11_...`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have it as of now, as [natural sorting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order) is simply not supported in AS' view - it just sorts alphabetically. The only workaround is to rename your assets and use fixed number of digits to achieve desired order. Something like this:

```
cat_01_
cat_02_
...
cat_11_
...
```

If you got more than 99 elements of given "sequence" then use three digits instead of two etc.

Answer (score -1):

This would also help you :

```
        for(int i=1; i<=99;i++){
            int drawableImageId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("cat__"+i+"_", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
            imageView.setImageResource(drawableImageId);
        }
```

or

```
    public int getCatImage(int pos) {
        int drawableImageId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("cat__" + pos + "_", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        return drawableImageId;

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily sort your list with a custom sort.

Have a look at `Collections.sort()`.